# Webrtc programacion con JAVA

Tags: javascript, java, kotlin, servidor, app

Hola estoy desarrollando un proyecto de DAM y estoy tratando de dar visibilidad a una app que  que conecte dos dispositivos a través de WebRTC, ¿alguien podría orientarme para ver los pasos que se seguirían en el caso de programar con JAVA la llamada al servidor de señalización y enviarle los protocolos de comunicación SDP para que me comunique con otro dispositivo. Es una pregunta de redes, pero querría saber si alguien sabría como programar esto con Java. Existiría alguna librería concretamente para este uso¿?

Gracias